# How to query mongo to find arrays that contain any of the elements from another array?

Tags: arrays, mongodb

I am having arrays in collection like this

```
{
arr: [1,3,4,6,7,0]
}
,
{
arr: [2,3,5,6]
},
{
arr: [2,6,7,9]
}
```

And if i make a query with another array say [2,5], it should return

```
{
arr: [2,3,5,6]
},
{
arr: [2,6,5,7,9]
}
```

Is this possible to do in mongo?

Comment: You can try an aggregation query using the [Set Expression Operators](https://docs.mongodb.com/v4.2/reference/operator/aggregation/#set-expression-operators).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply use `$in`

```
db.collection.find({
  arr: {
    $in: [
      2,
      5
    ]
  }
})
```

Working [Mongo playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/_qx_cDjOmWv)